# Ansible with VMWare to create Dictionary using Ansible

Tags: ansible, vmware

I am trying to create a dictionary with lists of items for a VMWare details collection. I was able to create the list individually. But not sure how to merge this.

```
- name: Gather DC info
  community.vmware.vmware_datacenter_info:
    hostname: "{{ vcenter_hostname }}"
    username: "{{ vcenter_username }}"
    password: "{{ vcenter_password }}"
    validate_certs: false
  register: datacenter_infor

- name: Set DC_name variable
  set_fact:
    # dc_name: "{{ item.name }}"
    dc_name: >-
      {{ (dc_name | default([]))
        + [item.name]
      }}
  loop: "{{ datacenter_infor.datacenter_info }}"

- name: Gather cluster info
  vmware_cluster_info:
    hostname: "{{ vcenter_hostname }}"
    username: "{{ vcenter_username }}"
    password: "{{ vcenter_password }}"
    validate_certs: false
    datacenter: "{{ item }}"
  register: cluster_info
  loop: "{{ dc_name }}"

- name: Set Host_name variable
  set_fact:
    host_name_list: >-
      {{ (host_name_list | default([]))
        + data
      }}
  vars:
    data: "{{ item.clusters.values() }}"
  loop: "{{ cluster_info.results }}"
```

This will result in below output:

```
TASK [Set Host_name variable] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item={'changed': False, 'clusters': {'PQR-CLU01': {'hosts': [{'name': 'PQR-cn0001.myhost.com', 'folder': '/PQR/host/PQR-CLU01'}, {'name': 'PQR-cn0002.myhost.com', 'folder': '/PQR/host/PQR-CLU01'}})
ok: [localhost] => (item={'changed': False, 'clusters': {'ABC-CLU01': {'hosts': [{'name': 'ABC-cn0002.myhost.com', 'folder': '/ABC/host/ABC-CLU01'}, {'name': 'ABC-cn0001.myhost.com', 'folder': '/ABC/host/ABC-CLU01'}})
```

How can I create a dictionary with above items like using ansible:

```
{'PQR-CLU01': ['PQR-cn0001.myhost.com','PQR-cn0002.myhost.com'],'ABC-CLU01':['ABC-cn0002.myhost.com','ABC-cn0001.myhost.com']
```

Answer (score 1):

Given the data

```yaml
cluster_info:
  results:
    - changed: false
      clusters:
        PQR-CLU01:
          hosts:
          - folder: /PQR/host/PQR-CLU01
            name: PQR-cn0001.myhost.com
          - folder: /PQR/host/PQR-CLU01
            name: PQR-cn0002.myhost.com
    - changed: false
      clusters:
        ABC-CLU01:
          hosts:
          - folder: /ABC/host/ABC-CLU01
            name: ABC-cn0002.myhost.com
          - folder: /ABC/host/ABC-CLU01
            name: ABC-cn0001.myhost.com
```

---

Q: ***"Create dictionary (below)."***

```yaml
cluster_dict:
    ABC-CLU01:
    - ABC-cn0002.myhost.com
    - ABC-cn0001.myhost.com
    PQR-CLU01:
    - PQR-cn0001.myhost.com
    - PQR-cn0002.myhost.com
```

A: Create the list of clusters

```yaml
cluster_list: "{{ cluster_info.results|
                  map(attribute='clusters')|
                  map('dict2items')|
                  flatten }}"
```

gives

```yaml
cluster_list:
  - key: PQR-CLU01
    value:
      hosts:
      - folder: /PQR/host/PQR-CLU01
        name: PQR-cn0001.myhost.com
      - folder: /PQR/host/PQR-CLU01
        name: PQR-cn0002.myhost.com
  - key: ABC-CLU01
    value:
      hosts:
      - folder: /ABC/host/ABC-CLU01
        name: ABC-cn0002.myhost.com
      - folder: /ABC/host/ABC-CLU01
        name: ABC-cn0001.myhost.com
```

Create a list of keys

```yaml
cluster_keys: "{{ cluster_list|
                  map(attribute='key')|
                  list }}"
```

gives

```yaml
cluster_keys:
  - PQR-CLU01
  - ABC-CLU01
```

Create a list of values

```yaml
cluster_vals: "{{ cluster_list|
                  map(attribute='value.hosts')|
                  map('map', attribute='name')|
                  list }}"
```

gives

```yaml
cluster_vals:
  - - PQR-cn0001.myhost.com
    - PQR-cn0002.myhost.com
  - - ABC-cn0002.myhost.com
    - ABC-cn0001.myhost.com
```

Crate the dictionary

```yaml
cluster_dict: "{{ dict(cluster_keys|zip(cluster_vals)) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
cluster_dict:
  ABC-CLU01:
    - ABC-cn0002.myhost.com
    - ABC-cn0001.myhost.com
  PQR-CLU01:
    - PQR-cn0001.myhost.com
    - PQR-cn0002.myhost.com
```

---

Example of a complete playbook

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:
    cluster_info:
      results:
        - changed: false
          clusters:
            PQR-CLU01:
              hosts:
              - folder: /PQR/host/PQR-CLU01
                name: PQR-cn0001.myhost.com
              - folder: /PQR/host/PQR-CLU01
                name: PQR-cn0002.myhost.com
        - changed: false
          clusters:
            ABC-CLU01:
              hosts:
              - folder: /ABC/host/ABC-CLU01
                name: ABC-cn0002.myhost.com
              - folder: /ABC/host/ABC-CLU01
                name: ABC-cn0001.myhost.com

    cluster_list: "{{ cluster_info.results|
                      map(attribute='clusters')|
                      map('dict2items')|
                      flatten }}"
    cluster_keys: "{{ cluster_list|
                      map(attribute='key')|
                      list }}"
    cluster_vals: "{{ cluster_list|
                      map(attribute='value.hosts')|
                      map('map', attribute='name')|
                      list }}"
    cluster_dict: "{{ dict(cluster_keys|zip(cluster_vals)) }}"

  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: cluster_dict
```

Comment: Thanks for the above reply. Is there any way I can make the same dictionary type with the below file content:

Comment: Thanks. How can make the same dictionary type with the below file content:
"ABC":
    "ABC-C01":
       - host: "ABC-cn0001"
         ipv4: "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"
         netmask: "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"
         gateway: "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"    
         prefixlen: "19"
       - host: "ABC-cn0002"
         ipv4: "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"
         netmask: "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"
         gateway: "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"
         prefixlen: "19"
"DEF":
  'DEF-cn0001":  ....

Output: {'ABC-C01': ['ABC-cn0001.myhost.com','ABC-cn0002.myhost.com'],'DEF-C01':['DEF-cn0001.myhost.com','DEF-cn0002.myhost.com']}

Comment: It's difficult to read the comment. Open a new question and put it there. Make it [mre], i.e. **valid!** YAML; **minimal!** e.g. instead of `"DEF": 'DEF-cn0001"` use `"d": "c1"`; use only as much items as needed to demonstrate the problem ...

Comment: Can you please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73738280/ansible-create-dictionary-from-an-intent-file

Comment: Can you please check your [YAML](http://www.yamllint.com/) first?

Comment: I have corrected it in the question and validated.

Comment: Can you please help me to resolve https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74021887/create-dictionary-from-ansible-inventory-file