# Create Dictionary from Ansible inventory file

Tags: ansible, vmware

I am trying to create a dictionary with below ansible inventory file.

```
    "myfile": {
        "all": {
            "hosts": null,
            "vars": {
                "ansible_connection": "local",
                "ansible_python_interpreter": "{{ ansible_playbook_python }}"
            }
        },
        "USA": {
            "children": {
                "MYDC1": {
                    "children": {
                        "MYDC1-CLU01": {
                            "hosts": {
                                "MYDC2-VM1": null,
                                "MYDC2-VM2": null,
                                "MYDC2-VM3": null,
                                "MYDC2-VM4": null,
                                "MYDC2-VM5": null,
                                "MYDC2-VM6": null
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                "MYDC2": {
                    "children": {
                        "MYDC2-CLU01": {
                            "hosts": {
                                "MYDC1-VM1": null
                                "MYDC1-VM2": null
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                "MYDC3": {
                    "children": {
                        "MYDC3-CLU01": {
                            "hosts": {
                                "MYDC3-VM1": null
                                "MYDC3-VM2": null
                                "MYDC3-VM3": null
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "vars": {
                "vcenter_hostname": "myvcenter.esxihost.com"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

From this file, expected output is:

```
{
'MYDC1-CLU01': ['MYDC1-VM1.myhost.com','MYDC1-VM2.myhost.com'],
'MYDC2-CLU01':['MYDC2-VM1.myhost.com','MYDC2-VM2.myhost.com','MYDC2-VM3.myhost.com','MYDC2-VM4.myhost.com','MYDC2-VM5.myhost.com','MYDC2-VM6.myhost.com'],
'MYDC3-CLU01':['MYDC3-VM1.myhost.com','MYDC3-VM2.myhost.com','MYDC3-VM3.myhost.com'],
}
```

The code given below works fine:

```
my_domain: myhost.com
my_groups: [MYDC1-CLU01, MYDC2-CLU01, MYDC3-CLU01]
cluster_dict: "{{ dict(my_groups|
                      zip(my_groups|
                          map('extract', groups)|
                          map('product', [my_domain])|
                          map('map', 'join', '.')|
                          list)) }}"
```

Output:

```
$ ansible-playbook main.yml -i hosts.yml
[WARNING]: Invalid characters were found in group names but not replaced, use -vvvv to see details

PLAY [Check Service status] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
TASK [Gathering Facts] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************ok: [localhost]

TASK [my_checks : Show host inventory file] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************ok: [localhost] => {
    "cluster_dict": {
        "MYDC1-CLU01": [
            "MYDC1-VM1.myhost.com",
            "MYDC1-VM2.myhost.com"
        ],
        "MYDC2-CLU01": [
            "MYDC2-VM1.myhost.com",
            "MYDC2-VM2.myhost.com",
            "MYDC2-VM3.myhost.com",
            "MYDC2-VM4.myhost.com",
            "MYDC2-VM5.myhost.com",
            "MYDC2-VM6.myhost.com"
        ],
        "MYDC3-CLU01": [
            "MYDC3-VM1.myhost.com",
            "MYDC3-VM2.myhost.com"
        ]
    }
}
```

I have 2 questions:

1: Is there anyway I can store variable in "cluster_dict" without passing the hosts.yml file in the command line. Like converting hosts file into below

```
host_intent_data: "{{ lookup('file', 'hosts.yml')|from_yaml }}"
```

and process the host_intent_data.

2. The CLUSTER/DC values will be growing each day and we can't use static fields as mentioned in my_groups.Is there any way we can get the desired dictionary dynamically?

Answer (score 1):

Given the inventory

```yaml
shell> cat hosts
all:
  hosts:
  vars:
    ansible_connection: local
    ansible_python_interpreter: '{{ ansible_playbook_python }}'

USA:
  children:
    MYDC1:
      children:
        MYDC_CLU01:
          hosts:
            MYDC1-VM1:
            MYDC1-VM2:
    MYDC2:
      children:
        MYDC2_CLU01:
          hosts:
            MYDC2-VM1:
            MYDC2-VM2:
            MYDC2-VM3:
            MYDC2-VM4:
            MYDC2-VM5:
            MYDC2-VM6:
  vars:
    vcenter_hostname: myvcenter.esxihost.com
```

and the variables

```yaml
    my_domain: myhost.com
    my_groups: [MYDC_CLU01, MYDC2_CLU01]
```

Put the below declaration into the *vars*

```yaml
    my_dict: "{{ dict(my_groups|
                      zip(my_groups|
                          map('extract', groups)|
                          map('product', [my_domain])|
                          map('map', 'join', '.')|
                          list)) }}"
```

gives what you want

```yaml
  my_dict:
    MYDC2_CLU01:
    - MYDC2-VM1.myhost.com
    - MYDC2-VM2.myhost.com
    - MYDC2-VM3.myhost.com
    - MYDC2-VM4.myhost.com
    - MYDC2-VM5.myhost.com
    - MYDC2-VM6.myhost.com
    MYDC_CLU01:
    - MYDC1-VM1.myhost.com
    - MYDC1-VM2.myhost.com
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  vars:

    my_domain: myhost.com
    my_groups: [MYDC_CLU01, MYDC2_CLU01]

    my_dict: "{{ dict(my_groups|
                      zip(my_groups|
                          map('extract', groups)|
                          map('product', [my_domain])|
                          map('map', 'join', '.')|
                          list)) }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: my_dict
      run_once: true
```

---

Q: ***"Convert hosts file to 'cluster_dict'."***

A: Use *ansible-inventory* and convert the file to yaml. Select the region (e.g. USA) and create the dictionary. For example, if you provide a valid inventory file

```yaml
cluster: "{{ lookup('pipe', 'ansible-inventory -i hosts.json --list --yaml')|from_yaml }}"
cluster_USA: "{{ cluster.all.children.USA.children|json_query('*.children') }}"
cluster_dict_raw: |
  {% for i in cluster_USA %}
  {{ i.keys()|first }}:
    {{ (i.values()|first).hosts.keys() }}
  {% endfor %}
cluster_dict: "{{ cluster_dict_raw|from_yaml }}"
```

gives

```yaml
cluster_dict:
  MYDC1-CLU01: [MYDC2-VM1, MYDC2-VM2, MYDC2-VM3, MYDC2-VM4, MYDC2-VM5, MYDC2-VM6]
  MYDC2-CLU01: [MYDC1-VM1, MYDC1-VM2]
  MYDC3-CLU01: [MYDC3-VM1, MYDC3-VM2, MYDC3-VM3]
```

Notes:

- Test the inventory file before complaining!

```yaml
shell> ansible-inventory -i hosts.json --list --yaml
```

- The names of the groups are not valid. You must have seen the warning. Fix it before complaining!

> [WARNING]: Invalid characters were found in group names ...

- Fit the template to your needs. For example, add domain and create FQDN

```yaml
cluster_dict_raw: |
  {% for i in cluster_USA %}
  {{ i.keys()|first }}:
    {{ (i.values()|first).hosts.keys()|product(['myhost.com'])|
                                       map('join', '.')|list }}
  {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Sorry. This didn't worked for me. I am trying to process this inventory file (not named as hosts) in my repo for eg: vmlist.yml and need to create the dictionary as mentioned for further testing for each cluster.  
Is there any way we can automate the my_groups as well because this value is not static. New Clusters will be coming and doesn't need to add this everytime.

Comment: I can't help you if you don't provide [mre]. [edit] your question and describe what you want (minimal, complete, and reproducible). (Nobody is interested in how the inventory is **not** named).

Comment: I have added the question with correct details. It would be great, if you could help me to find a solution. Thanks in advance.
Please let me know if any other information is needed.

Comment: Thank you so much. You are awesome :) This was exactly I was looking for. 
But when we check the cluster_dict it is missing  adding the "myhost.com" in the hostvalues. Can you please add it as well in the code.

Comment: I added an example. Open new questions if have other issues.

Comment: It worked. Thank you so much. 
I don't know how much I can thank you for this help. 
Is there any way I can review/rank your profile,I would have given 5 star. Thanks again :)

Comment: Sorry 1 last query, I need to add the variable "my_domain" not static 'myhost.com' inside "cluster_dict_raw"

=====
    {{ (i.values()|first).hosts.keys()|product(['myhost.com'])|
                                       map('join', '.')|list }}
=====

I have tried below and didn't worked:
=======
    {{ (i.values()|first).hosts.keys()|product(['{{ my_domain }}'])|
                                       map('join', '.')|list }}
=====

Comment: Put the variable in the place of the string `[my_domain]`.

Comment: Can you please suggest me your thoughts on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74122848/process-vmware-activity-with-dynamic-invenotry-in-ansible  >> Created new request.
This will the last request. Sorry to bother. Thanks